# Which libraries can be used for creating a poker game?

Tags: java, python, poker

There doesn't seem to be a good no-limit texas hold'em poker implementation on most Linux distros, I hope to change this and i've tried in the past to use the typical libraries (such as libgdx and its forks) but I feel these libraries are designed moreso for typical 30/60-fps action type games and less so for turn-based games.

I was wondering if anyone had some experience with making a similar game and had some success with a different library. If you could throw a few libraries/suggestions my way please let me know with some reasons for your choice.

My programming experience is <= a junior developer, and i'd prefer if the library was for Java or Python3.

Forgive me if this is a little too open-ended, but i'm really having trouble finding a suitable library to implement this sort of a turn-based game.

Comment: Check out my http://github.com/lcrocker/ojcardlib for the card-management stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/).

Comment: Yeah i've looked into this one as well but it seems to have the same problem as libgdx, it's more for (non-turn-based games). If you take a look at the projects there arent any sophisticated turn-based card games developed with it